# Text sidenote float

Tags: css

[image: sample image]

This is the layout I'm trying to achieve, with red div being the side note floated right. I got the floating part working but I do get a gap in text (red outline) due to the div being `relative`. How do I assign coordinates to the div (top offset) and not have the gap where its original position in flow is? Or is placing the div in the desired position within the flow the only way to approach this?

```
    #article {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }

    #sideNote {
        position:relative; // produces gap but I'd like to assign offset
        float:right;
        width:35%;
        background:red;
    }

<div id='article'>
   ....
   <div id='sideNote'>
     ....
   </div>
</div>
```

The main thing is that in order to assign `top:xxem` to the red div I need it to have coordinates matrix, something that can only be achieved by assigning `position` from what I understand, `absolute` does not work in this case as it does not provide text runaround and `relative` leaves the gap in original flow

Comment: #sidenote should stand first int the flow of #article if you want it ont top right.

Comment: yes but how do I offset it from the top without making it `relative`?

Comment: Can you make a codepen or a fiddle , i'm getting confuse from your drawing and my average understanding of english, thanks

Comment: Here is a simple fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FcsBb/ - Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: yes but can the red div be half way down the middle (vertically)? @GCyrillus, please refer to this jsfiddle

Comment: something like this would be a hint for you ? http://jsfiddle.net/FcsBb/1/

Comment: yes, maybe I can work this out this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I updated @timspqr 's fiddle and this is probably what you are looking for.

You can manage the drop % for the note using `calc`

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/FcsBb/5/